# start T in matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In many start equations I see T (transpose) or -1 (inverse). Why is there using T, but not original matrix?

Example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula
($\mathbf{A}$ + $\mathbf{U}$*$\mathbf{Q}^\top$)

Why is there transpose matrix in start is more practical then use in other part? In start conditions we have $\mathbf{Q}$, but not $\mathbf{Q}^\top$.

With kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

In Morrison’s formula the $u$ and $v$ are *column vectors*. It is more natural to say both are (column) vectors and write $uv^T$ than to say that $u$ is a column vector and $v$ a row vector.